# where is the main method in the sbt source code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I clone the sbt source code,try to study it,but can't find

```
def main
```

or

```
extends App
```

even in sbt\main\src\main\scala\sbt\Main.scala

I search all the source file,find some file have the main method,but all these file are in the test floder,I think these method are the the main method of sbt

So where is the main method of sbt?Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to find it fast on *nix based system

Find pid of java process that launches `sbt`

```
ps aux | grep java
0:35.42 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx3g -Xss2m -jar /.sbt/launchers/1.3.3/sbt-launch.jar shell
```

This tells you that the main class is located in `sbt-launch.jar` jar file

Send signal 3 to the JVM or use jstack to get thread dump of the JVM

```
 kill -3 xxxx
```

And here it is

```
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:39)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ultimately it's the main method in sbt-launcher

https://github.com/sbt/launcher/blob/1.x/launcher-implementation/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Boot.scala

from Main

```
/** This class is the entry point for sbt. */
final class xMain extends xsbti.AppMain { 
  ...
}
```

you can see how it extends AppMain from the launcher project. Im not sure about the magic involved to make this work though.